# Conditional index in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I know from using Oracle that conditonal index with CASE statement is possible. But is it possible in PostgreSQL? For example index is following:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_INDEXNAME ON SOME_TABLE (
     CASE 
        WHEN COLUMN1 = 0 AND COLUMN2 = 'value' THEN SOME1_ID
        ELSE SOME2_ID
     END);
```

This is already modified version for PostgreSQL, because Oracle case statement is different from Postgres. If this is possbile how do I do that? Or if this is not possible, is there another way to realize it?

Comment: Yes this is possible. What is your question?

Comment: If this is possible, how do I do that? :)

Comment: Doesn't the `create index` work that you have? If not, was is the error?

Comment: [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the `CASE` expression in parentheses:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_INDEXNAME ON SOME_TABLE (
     (CASE 
        WHEN COLUMN1 = 0 AND COLUMN2 = 'value' THEN SOME1_ID
        ELSE SOME2_ID
     END) );
```